# Database file is not found on android

Tags: android

I just created a new project with AndroidStudio. I created a db file in `app/src/main/assets/databases`. My `app/app.iml` has this value :

```
<option name="ASSETS_FOLDER_RELATIVE_PATH" value="/src/main/assets" />
```

And I added this in my source code :

```
if(getDatabasePath("map.db").exists()) {
    Log.v("MyApplication", "exists");
} else {
    Log.v("MyApplication", "not exists");
}
```

I have the message "not exists".

I have this structure :

```
app/src/main/assets
├── databases
│   └── map.db
└── map.db (just to be sure)
```

In the File Explorer, of Android Device Monitor, I don't have the file.

Is there a solution?

Comment: If you are trying to ship a database, via `assets/`, as a starter database for your app, [use `SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper). The database is not automagically copied from `assets/` into your internal storage for you otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getDatabasePath` looks for the database into `/data/data/packagename.yourapp/databases`, not into the `assets/` folder.

Edit. You have to copy the file from the assets folder in
The correct location at runtime. You can use `SQLiteAssetsHelper` as suggested by @CommonsWare

Comment: Yes, but assets/ is not a distinct part of the filesystem at runtime, but rather something special remaining within the apk object which has its own limited access methods, so it is not merely a matter of looking in the right place, but also one of copying from there to somewhere on the filesystem.

Comment: I agree with you @ChrisStratton.

Comment: @ChrisStratton what is your solution? My file is a map which I want to use with MapBox. @Blackbelt, your right but I created a folder `app/src/main/databases` and I does not work too.

Comment: The solution is to copy the dabase you put in the asses/ in the correct folder. You can use the `SQLiteAssetsHelper` as suggested by @CommonsWare